# How to allow a number with digit limit and without decimal,and negative ina textfield using AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here is my code.But its not working in my directive .Please help me to show errors

When initially run I enter characters(other than number) in two times it will allowed. For Eg press 'W' in two times it will allwed in that textfield.
What is the error in this code?

Here is my script

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('nksOnlyNumber', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
      require: 'ngModel',      
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {   
     scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        var spiltArray = String(newValue).split("");

        if(attrs.allowNegative == "false") {
          if(spiltArray[0] == '-') {
        newValue = newValue.replace("-", "");
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
        ngModel.$render();
          }
        }

        if(attrs.allowDecimal == "false") {
        newValue = parseInt(newValue);
        ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
        ngModel.$render();
        }

        if(attrs.allowDecimal != "false") {
          if(attrs.decimalUpto) {
         var n = String(newValue).split(".");
         if(n[1]) {
            var n2 = n[1].slice(0, attrs.decimalUpto);
            newValue = [n[0], n2].join(".");
            ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
            ngModel.$render();
         }
          }
        }

        if(attrs.limitDigit=="true"){
         // attr.$set("ngTrim", "false");
          var limitLength = parseInt(attrs.awLimitLength, 10);// console.log(attrs);

        if(ngModel.$viewValue.length>limitLength){
          newValue = ngModel.$viewValue.substring(0, limitLength);
          ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue );
          ngModel.$render();
        }

        }              

        if (spiltArray.length === 0) return;
        if (spiltArray.length === 1 && (spiltArray[0] == '-' || spiltArray[0] === '.' )) return;
        if (spiltArray.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;

          /*Check it is number or not.*/
          if (isNaN(newValue)) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue);
        ngModel.$render();
          }
      });
      }
  };
});
```

Here is my  textfield in html file

```
<b>NumberLimited Only 4 Digits</b><br>
<input type="text" nks-only-number ng-model="mynumber6" aw-limit-length="4" allow-decimal="false" allow-negative="false" limit-digit="true" /><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following directives

```
    /*
    *Directive to Numbers only
    *use - numbers-only
    */

    myApp.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
        return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
            if (text) {
                var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                if (transformedInput !== text) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            }
            return false;
            }            
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
        };
    });

    /*
    *Directive to Max legth to prevent type
    *use - my-maxlength
    */

    myApp.directive('myMaxlength', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          var maxlength = Number(attrs.myMaxlength);
          function fromUser(text) {
          if (text.length > maxlength) {
            var transformedInput = text.substring(0, maxlength);
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
            return transformedInput;
          } 
          return text;
          }
          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
      }; 
    })
```

And use like

```
       <input name="field1"
              type="text" 
              ng-model="model1" 
              numbers-only 
              my-maxlength="4">
```

Hopes this will help you !

Comment: HI Santhosh Bhai is negative number is allowed in your code rit. Please give me your mail id i will send you my entire code

Comment: I am a  beginner in AngularJS

Comment: santoshshinde2012@gmail.com

Comment: Please check once again no negative number accept at my side

Answer (score 0):

Had something similar recently. Altered the input box:

```
<input {normal attributes here} data-ng-keydown="vm.checkNumber($event)" max="9999" />
```

Then in my controller:

```
vm.checkNumber = checkNumber;

function checkNumber(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (([9, 8, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(keyCode) > -1) ||
        (keyCode >= 49 && keyCode <= 57) ||
        (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105)) {
        return;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear rrd. How can i implement this in my code.Please help me I am in struggle